# Computed observable still trigger write even i dispose of it. Is that the correct behaviour?

Tags: knockout.js

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.firstName = ko.observable('Planet');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Earth');
    this.computedState = ko.observable(false);

    this.fullName = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            console.log("READ");            
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(); 
        },
        write: function (value) {
            console.log("WRITE");    
            var lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) { // Ignore values with no space character
                this.firstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); // Update "firstName"
                this.lastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); // Update "lastName"
            }
        },
        owner: this,

        disposeWhen : function(){ return self.computedState(); }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Computed observable still trigger write even i dispose of it. Is that correct behaviour ? I dont get the reason.     [JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/smwwb/)

Comment: could you explain a little more, what your problems exactly is?

Comment: Actually i dont have a problem i am trying to understand its behaviour. That doesnt make sense to trigger write even i disposed of it. Is there any benefit that i cant see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disposing a computed observable will make it clean up all of its subscriptions.  So, while you could still write to it, the `read` function will not run again.  Disposal does not null out the computed, it is meant to make sure that there are no lingering subscriptions.

For example, in this updated sample try disposing the computed and altering the `firstName` field.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/smwwb/13/